# php curl immediately redirect if got 3xx status code

Tags: php, curl, http-status-codes

I am creating web scraping with php and curl. I look that if the status code of http respond is 3xx, curl still download the body content. If the body content is small I think this is no problem, but In my case there are pages with 3xx and huge body content. I just want to redirect immediately if it got 3xx without getting the body content. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First you need [to tell it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) that only statuses less than 4xx are good.

```
$handle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
```

> CURLOPT_FAILONERROR
>   TRUE to fail silently if the HTTP code returned is
>   greater than or equal to 400. The default behavior is to return the
>   page normally, ignoring the code.

Second, for 3xx errors you need to follow the redirects. See `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` and `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS`.

Comment: even we use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, curl stil getting the body content before redirect. I just want to skip this.